# Как записать весь результат выполнения в файл java

Tags: java

Ломаю голову второй день как записать все выполнение цикла в текстовый файл от 1,2,3 с новой строки и тд. до 9999999999. Пробовал уменьшить до массив 99999999 отработало в текстовом файле только 6924971 строка и в каждой стороке 0. с массивом 9999999999 выдает ошибку

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
>       at Main.main(Main.java:7)

вот весь код

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\test\\1.txt";
    float [] array = new float[(int) 9999999999f];
    try (final FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filePath, true)) {
        for (int i = (int) 1f; i < array.length; i++) {
          final String s = Integer.toString((int) array[i]);
            writer.write(s);
            writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Так у вас  в массиве ноли. И зачем вообще массив? Просто в цикле записывайте в файл `i`.

Comment: И да, массив `float`-ов длиной `9999999999` съест 300 ГБ оперативной памяти.

Comment: @Nofate по-моему, 30 ГБ :)

Comment: Да действительно без массива все работает, но при объявлении long i1 =  9999999999 или int i1 =  9999999999 ругается IDEA подчеркивает красным. как выполнить весь процесс от 1 до 9999999999 ?

Comment: @Ladence 9999999999*32/1024/1024/1024 == 298.023224

Comment: У класса Arrays есть прекрасные способы вывода содержимого массивов

Answer (score 0):

Выдаваемое исключение информирует о том, что Вы использовали всю выделяемую под виртуальную машину память. Дело в том, что в Вашей задаче и не нужен массив вовсе (просто выводите индекс и все).

Answer (score -2):

Вопрос решился сам собой :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Home\\Desktop\\test\\1.txt";
    long i1 =  9999999999l;
    try (final FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filePath, false)) {
        for (long i = 1l; i < i1; i++) {
          final String s = Long.toString(i);
            writer.write(s);
            writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```